# Smoothly Animated scrollView in React Native

Tags: listview, animation, react-native, scrollview

[image: Smoothly Animated scrollView in React Native]

I'm having a problem in part of my project and I've always tried and still did not have a good result.

The tattoos were designed for this theme from several different scenarios and each had certain defects.

**But the issue**

I want a list with a bar above it to be animated in Y, so that:

1. When the list has not reached the top of the page, its scroll is disabled
2. And when the list reaches the top of the page it begins to scroll
3. And when the user scrolls down the list below:

   - If the list is first, the list will be drawn
   - Otherwise, it scrolls normally.
4. And when the user scrolls up the list above:

   - If the list has not risen to the top, the list will be pulled up and stick up
   - And if it comes up, it will start scrolling.

## Note (important)

- Animation must move smoothly
- Ability to move up and down the list in any case via the top bar

This is the code I wrote [Snack.Expo.Io](https://snack.expo.io/By_iZCpzQ).